# How do I find out what the "system defined" socket timeout and connect timeout are?

Tags: java, timeout, httpclient, default

The Apache HTTP RequestConfig [getSocketTimeout()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getSocketTimeout()) and [getConnectTimeout()](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-4.5.x/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig.html#getConnectTimeout()) both say:

> A negative value is interpreted as undefined (system default if applicable).

And they both say the default value is:

> Default: -1

So I'm using the default value of -1, but what is the "system default" value?  Is there some way I can find this by running a command on my terminal or something?

Comment: The default will likely depend on your operating system and other details like that. See here for Linux: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1045964/how-to-view-change-socket-connection-timeout-on-linux

Comment: `cat /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_syn_retries` shows 6 on my machine, but I think this is the *number* of retries, right?  Is there a similar way to view the duration of each attempt (aka the socket timeout)?

Comment: The default read timeoit is infinity on all platforms. The default connect timeout is of the order of a minute, but it varies by platform. Each SYN retry uses double the timeout of the previous one.